# How can we define Freemarker custom directives rendering order?

Tags: templates, freemarker

I am trying to render freemarker template's custom directives in specific order. The Default Behaviour is top to bottom rendering. But in my case some directives in top has dependency  on directives in bottom and therefore rendering order needs to be reversed. I know it can be done in two phases but i would prefer to render in one phase.

Comment: Does the top directive enclose the bottom directives in its nested content? Like `<@top>...<@bottom/>...</@top>`.

Comment: no, no nested tags.

Comment: That's unfortunate... So, no, directives are executed sequentially. Things like that can only be solved with `Writer` tricks, that is, by reserving the place where you insert the top content later. There's no out of box support for that though.